# How to set a blurry image Library without Onclick listener

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-library, android-blur-effect

I am trying to set a blur image library from
https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry
 But I am it is not working without onclick listener here is my java code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Blurry.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .radius(25)
                        .sampling(2)
                        .async()
                        .animate(500)
                        .onto((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relate));

}
```

But when I set the blurry under on click listener it works so can some one tell me how I can do this without on click listener

Comment: using Glide library it's really better than any other 3rd party libs.

Comment: what you need just blur image ?

Comment: refer [this](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript)

Comment: yes I am just trying to blur Image so that when the user open the app it will show a blur image in background

Comment: @SAVVY are U dynamically loading the image from url  please let me know

Comment: No I am not loading the image dynamically @NikhilSingh just manualy

Comment: the following library is the most easy one I updated the question thx for the following library